# ASCII safe serialization of protocol buffers

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I need to pass Protocol Buffers structures as ASCII strings (actually UTF8 strings, but ASCII would also do). Is there any out of the box solution in C++ ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [`TextFormat`](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format.html) class with its `Parse` and `Print` functions. I can't remember offhand how that treats non-ASCII string fields, so you should check that, but it's the general support for text in Protocol Buffers. Various other platforms support the same format, so it's still portable.

Comment: It's too verbose. Not much better than JSON

Comment: @Alexey: You didn't ask for a concise textual serialization format. You asked how to pass protocol buffers as ASCII strings. I answered the question you asked - if you wanted to know something else, you should have asked the question you were really interested in.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be lazy you could always [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) the binary output.